# Thread safe writing to Lucene index files

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool, web-crawler

I have an application that crawls a site and writes the content as lucene index files into the physical directory.

When I use threads for this purpose, I am getting write errors or errors due to the locks.

I want to use multiple threads and write into the index files without missing the task of any of the threads.

```
public class WriteDocument
{
    private static Analyzer _analyzer;

    private static IndexWriter indexWriter;

    private static string Host;

    public WriteDocument(string _Host)
    {
        Host = _Host;
        Lucene.Net.Store.Directory _directory = FSDirectory.GetDirectory(Host, false);
        _analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
        bool indexExists = IndexReader.IndexExists(_directory);
        bool createIndex = !indexExists;

        indexWriter = new IndexWriter(_directory, _analyzer, true);
    }
    public void AddDocument(object obj)
    {
           DocumentSettings doc = (DocumentSettings)obj;               
           Field urlField = new Field("Url", doc.downloadedDocument.Uri.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.TOKENIZED);
            document.Add(urlField);
            indexWriter.AddDocument(document);

            document = null;
            doc.downloadedDocument = null;

            indexWriter.Optimize();
            indexWriter.Close();
      }
}
```

To the above class, I am passing the values like this:

```
DocumentSettings writedoc = new DocumentSettings()
{
      Host = Host,
      downloadedDocument = downloadDocument
};
Thread t = new Thread(() =>
{
doc.AddDocument(writedoc);
});
t.Start();
```

If I add `t.Join();` after `t.Start();` the code works for me without any errors. But this slows down my process and virtually, this is equal to the output I get without using threads.

I am getting error like:

```
Cannot rename /indexes/Segments.new to /indexes/Segments 
the file is used by some other process.
```

Can anyone help me on this code?

Comment: What errors do you get? Can we see a small example of the code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

An IndexWriter is not thread safe, so this is not possible.

If you want to use multiple threads for download, you will need to build some sort of "message pump" that is singlethreaded, to which you can feed the Documents you are downloading and creating, and puts them in a queue.

Example, in your AddDocument method, instead of utilizing the index directly, just send them of to a service that will index it eventually.

That service should try to index everything in queue all the time, and if it doesn't have a queue for the time being, sleep for a while.

Comment: well, I'm confused - Lucene.net 3.0.3 docs says IndexWriter are [thread-safe](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d2/d1d/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_index_1_1_index_writer.html#details)

Answer (score 0):

An approach you can take would be to create a separate index for each of the threads and merge them all back at the end. e.g. index1, index2...indexn (corresponding to threads 1..n) and merge them.